# Type 'UIImagePickerControllerSourceType' has no member 'photoLibrary'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is the code:

```
 // Only allow photos to be picked,not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
```

this is the error: Type 'UIImagePickerControllerSourceType' has no member 'photoLibrary'

Just trying to complete the official tutorial Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)

```
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    //Hide the keyboard.
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagepickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked,not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    //Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, competion: nil)
}
@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
}
```

}

Comment: What you have shown for your code looks exactly like what I do. Could you post a bit more code? Particularly how you are instantiating the controller.

Comment: Sorry i'm new and this is my first question.

Comment: There is also a second error present(imagePickerController, animated: true, competion: nil)

Comment: is it maybe because my Xcode is not up to date? Thats what i'm thinking, which sucks because I'm just trying to follow a tutorial and before i can finish it they come out with new updates that mess up the code

Comment: My code is set up a bit differently, but nothing that jumps out at me to not build. What version of Swift are you using? I'll dig up my Swift 2.x code if needed.

Comment: Xcode Version 7.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you are probably usingSwift 2.2 (maybe it's this for Swift 2.3 also). You want this syntax:

```
imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
```

Note the capitalization. Keep in mind, Xcode 8.2 (released 12 December 2016) will be the last version of Xcode to support Swift 2.x. Sometime in 2017 you will probably need to use Swift 3 for new App Store submissions.

EDIT:

Here's my full Swift 2.2 code, followed by my Swift 3.0 code. Please note two things:

- I'm also using the Camera app and have checks to make sure it's present - which isn't the case for the simulator.
- Your app **will** crash in iOS 10 unless you add the following to your info.plist file:

  NSCameraUsageDescription
  Used to capture new image for photo effect
  NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
  Used to select an image for photo effect

You may put different values in the  tags.

Swift 2.2:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self
}

extension SelectViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Camera App

    func openCameraApp() {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
            presentViewController(picker,
                                  animated: true,
                                  completion: nil)
        } else {
            noCamera()
        }
    }
    func noCamera(){
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(
            title: "No Camera",
            message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style:.Default,
            handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(
            alertVC,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Photos Albums

    func showImagePicker() {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        //        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        presentViewController(picker,
                              animated: true,
                              completion: nil)
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        image = chosenImage
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowEditView", sender: self)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Seque to EditViewController

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowEditView" {
            if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? EditViewController {
                vc.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 3.0 (only the extension code has syntax changes):

```
func openCameraApp() {
    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(picker,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
    } else {
        noCamera()
    }
}
func noCamera(){
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(
        title: "No Camera",
        message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
        preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style:.default,
        handler: nil)
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    present(
        alertVC,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}

// MARK: Photos Albums

func showImagePicker() {
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    //        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    present(picker,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    image = chosenImage
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowEditView", sender: self)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: Seque to EditViewController

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEditView" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? EditViewController {
            vc.image = image
            //                vc.image = images[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thank you, and i know, i am just going through a tutorial, so all it was was the capital P, thats crazy

Comment: would you happen to know whats going on with present(imagePickerController, animated: true, competion: nil) ?

Comment: That's part of the Swift 3 formatting changes. There are quite a few. Happily, most of these will automatically be updated through the migration wizard in Xcode 8.

Comment: ah ok so if i update to the latest it will automatically update my errors

Comment: Yes. Since Xcode 8.x has been out since mid-September and is a free download, I'd recommend getting it. I haven't found too much pain in upgrading my code to Swift 3.0 - the migration tool is pretty good - and sooner or later you will need to. I'm finding most code you find out there is in Swift 3. I think you can still open your old projects in Xcode 7.x, but Xcode 8 will become the default app.

Comment: "Keep in mind, if you are using Swift 2.2 (and very soon Swift 2.3) you won't be able to submit to the App Store." that's not true

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit inaccurate. Xcode 8.2 will be the last version of Xcode to support Swift 2.3. I'll update that comment, but the bottom line is that support for Swift 2.x **is** going away, probably (in my opinion) before WWDC '17. Thanks for clarifying.